# How do I check my entries in column and remove if it is not correct?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R. I want to check my entries in my column which is in a dataframe then remove the entry if it is not correct. In my column there should be only 1 and 2 but sometimes I do see 0. I want to remove 0. Can I use na.omite() function?

Comment: Try: `cleanData <- myData[ myData$myColumn != 0, ]`

Comment: Will it remove only 0?

Comment: Yes, it will keep rows that are not zero, or if you wish to keep rows with certain values, try: `cleanData <- myData[ myData$myColumn %in% c(1, 2), ]`. Please see the linked post, and read up on R basics.